# use x86 dll in x64 application C#

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit

I have an sdk. it is written in C++ for x86 And I need to use this dll in an x64 application!
I use this dll in the x86 app and all was good! But the x86 app in windows can use only 1.4 Gb. It is too small for my app. How can I increase this?

Comment: If you are using C++ (question), why do the question title and tags say C#? these are *very* different beasts. Can you be **very** clear which it is, please? Also, x86 in windows can use 2GB, potentially 3GB if you have the OS-level 3GB flag enabled

Comment: Rewrite the SDK to use 64-bit memory addressing if you have access to the source code. Have its makers do it for you if you don't have the code.

Comment: Marc Gravell, how enable this flag?

Answer (score 2):

If the source code to the SDK is available you can try compiling it for a 64bit target. If the SDK does not have a set of validation tests this may be difficult and there may be problems that are not immediately apparent. IF the source code is not available, a 64bit version of the SDK is not available and there is a slim chance that one will not be available in the future you do have at least one option available to you.

It *is* possible to use a 32bit DLL in a 64bit application by wrapping it in a COM interface and using `dllhost` to act as a surrogate to handle the marshaling. It is not a difficult process but may have an impact on performance when arguments are marshaled and the function is called but will not impact the actual function itself.

Create your set of 32bit COM objects that wrap the SDK and register them as normal. Make sure each object is registered with an application id, this is important. The additional steps outlined below will allow you to use them in a 64bit application through the `dllhost` surrogate.

- If you have registered the objects correctly there will be a key in the registry for each object - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\[APPID]\[GUID]`. `[APPID]` is the application id of the object and `[GUID]` is the GUID of the object.
- Under each key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\[APPID]\[GUID]` add a new string value (`REG_SZ`) and name it `DllSurrogate`. Leave the value empty.
- Create a new key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\[APPID]\[GUID]`. You do not have to add any additional subkeys or values.

[Note: How you design the COM interfaces and implement the co-classes is up to you. I have not included documentation on registering the objects as this is a common process. The only difference in using them with a surrogate which is included above. The existing information on MSDN and countless other sites is more than sufficient to help you register the objects.]